# Rename tag [background-fetch] to [ios-background-fetch]

Tags: support, retag-request

The tag [background-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background-fetch) should be renamed to `ios-background-fetch` since the term is specific to iOS and currently all questions tagged with [background-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background-fetch) are also tagged with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) or [ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios7), [ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios8), etc.

Comment: Well, there's even a service in Windows for background-fetching: BITS. No idea how it compares though. Anyway, renaming the tag doesn't seem that useful.